# Delete non alphabetic characters at the starting of String

Tags: ios, swift, string

I want to replace all the non-alphanumeric characters (including white spaces) of a string up to the first alphabet

```
"\r\n                A Simple PDF File \r\n                   This is a small demonstration .pdf file - \r\n                   just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more \r\n                   text."
```

I used

```
 let string = txtView.text
 let newString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")
```

but it replaces all the "\n" of string. how could we replace the starting characters only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to remove leading white spaces using regular expression. This is the code :

```
extension String {
    func trimLeadingWhitespaces() -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "^\\s+", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
    }
}

let string = "       Some string     abc"
let trimmed = string.trimLeadingWhitespaces()
print(trimmed)
```

Comment: You may form your own regex by referring 
 : http://regexrenamer.sourceforge.net/help/regex_quickref.html

Comment: Taking the question literally the regex is rather `"^[^[:alnum:]]+"`

Answer (score 1):

There is a function `drop` that removes characters while a condition is filled.

Here are two variants of using it

```
let newString = string.drop { $0.isWhitespace || $0.isPunctuation }
let newString = string.drop { !($0.isLetter || $0.isNumber) }
```

Comment: You can trailing closure syntax  `drop { ... }`

Comment: Note that isLetter doesn’t include digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trimmingCharacters` method of string class. It will remove all the leading and trailing whitespaces and \n from string.

```
let str = "\r\n                A Simple PDF File \r\n                   This is a small demonstration .pdf file - \r\n                   just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more \r\n                   text."

let result = str.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
print(result)
```

Comment: i don't need to remove trailing or middle space or new lines just to remove leading spaces

Comment: @AwaisMobeen Add the output that you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Only leading spaces:

```
extension String {
    func removingLeadingSpaces() -> String {
        guard let index = firstIndex(where: { !CharacterSet(charactersIn: String($0)).isSubset(of: .whitespaces) }) else {
            return self
        }
        return String(self[index...])
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use character property `isWhitespace` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character

Answer (score 0):

you can use two `func` from `extension` (thx @amer):

```
extension String {
    func replacingFirstOccurrence(of string: String, with replacement: String) -> String {
        guard let range = self.range(of: string) else { return self }
        return replacingCharacters(in: range, with: replacement)
    }

    func removingLeadingSpaces() -> String {
        guard let index = firstIndex(where: { !CharacterSet(charactersIn: String($0)).isSubset(of: .whitespaces) }) else {
            return self
        }
        return String(self[index...])
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
let myString = "\r\n                A Simple PDF File \r\n                   This is a small demonstration .pdf file - \r\n                   just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more \r\n                   text."


let charactersRemoved = myString.replacingFirstOccurrence(of: "\r\n", with: "")
let whiteSpacesRemoved = charactersRemoved.removingLeadingSpaces()
print(whiteSpacesRemoved) // "A Simple PDF File \r\n                   This is a small demonstration .pdf file - \r\n                   just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more \r\n                   text."
```

Answer (score 0):

`[ |\t|\n|\r]` matchs for space, newline, tabulation or carriage return

`{2,}` "2 times or more"

each match is replaced with a newline

```swift
let str = "\r\n                A Simple PDF File \r\n                   This is a small demonstration .pdf file - \r\n                   just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more \r\n                   text."

let newString = str.replacingOccurrences(
    of: "[ |\t|\n|\r]{2,}",
    with: "\n",
    options: .regularExpression
)
print(newString)
// A Simple PDF File
// This is a small demonstration .pdf file -
// just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more
// text.
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem statement you need to delete non-alphabetic char which includes `spaces, line,'@','$','%','^'`, etc. There is much non-alphabetic char. Instead of checking non-alphabetic char , you chan validate alphabetic char alone. Please check the following solution to your problem.

```
extension String{
    func findFirstAlphabetic() -> String.Index?{
        for index  in self.indices{
            if String(self[index]).isAlphanumeric == true{
                return index
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
    var isAlphanumeric: Bool {
        return !isEmpty && range(of: "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", options: .regularExpression) == nil
    }
    func alphabetic_Leading_SubString() -> String?{
        if let startIndex =  self.findFirstAlphabetic(){
            let newSubString = self[startIndex..<self.endIndex]
            return String(newSubString)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

usage:-

```
print("Output" + string.alphabetic_Leading_SubString())
```

Input :-

```
let string = "\r\n@ # $ % & ^ * () -+ #####@@@                A Simple PDF File \r\n                   This is a small demonstration .pdf file - \r\n                   just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more \r\n                   text."
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: `@Awais Mobeen` Please check this solves your problem